# Bookdown: unnumbered sections no longer collapse

Tags: bookdown, sections, tableofcontents

The collapsing of my bookdown document changed unexpectedly. I verified this with the bookdown demo.

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  split_by: section
  number_sections: false
  toc_depth: 3
  config:
    toc:
      collapse: section
```

With the above settings, all sections are uncollapsed in the TOC.

With `number_sections: true`, only numbered sections collapse, any unnumbered ones (using `{-}`) won't collapse.

Comment: has anyone filed an issue on this?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same behavior yesterday (unnumbered sections of bookdown::gitbook toc would not collapse where they had previously). After exploring variants in my _output.yml file, I rolled back my rmarkdown package to v2.11 (from v2.13) and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I did check that for the bookdown package but that did not help - makes sense that it was rmarkdown. I hope it gets fixed though!